# Cohn's Fatou lemma

Tags: measure-theory

Theorem 2.4.4 (Fatou's Lemma). Let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $\left\{f_n\right\}$ be a sequence of $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$. Then
$$
\int \underline{\lim } f_n d \mu \leq \underline{\lim } \int f_n d \mu
$$

Am I missing something that excludes why this shouldn't apply to the $f_n=\sup _{k \geq n} g_k$ of a positive sequence? In my uni class we only use the definition that applies for $f_n=\inf _{k \geq n} g_k$ and use the Monotone convergence theorem to prove it. I understand why the inequality is reversed for the supremum of a sequence so I'm wondering why the definition in Cohn's Measure theory book is phrased this way. I must be missing something so if someone could clarity what I'm glossing over that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up the statement with the proof itself. In the *statement*, since $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ defined by $f_n=\sup_{k\ge n}g_k$ for all $n$ would be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions, it is correct to apply the theorem and conclude: $$\int_X\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}g_k\,\mathrm{d}\mu\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_X\sup_{k\ge n}g_k\,\mathrm{d}\mu$$

Make of that what you will.

However, in the proof, we don't use Fatou's lemma (because that would be circular). We use the monotone convergence theorem, as you say, *and crucially we use the fact that $f_n:=\inf_{k\ge n}g_k$ is a monotone increasing sequence*. $n\mapsto\sup_{k\ge n}g_k$ does *not* define a monotone increasing sequence, it in fact defines a monotone *decreasing* sequence and the monotone convergence theorem cannot be applied in its basic form without further hypotheses.

Comment: I just realised all my confusion was because I hadn't seen the bar under the limit implying it was lim inf. But thankyou for the explanation.